# How good a practice is this?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Say I have a Java application which handles thousands of users. So for each user action a certain block of code will be executed repeatedly and I am creating millions of temporary objects. I write my method this way.

```
public void myMethod(ClassB a, ClassA b) {
    ClassC c = null;
    ClassD d = null;

    try {
        c = new ClassC();
        d = new ClassD();

        // Some code which uses a, b, c, d.
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        a = null;
        b = null;
        if (c != null) {
            c = null;
        }
        if (d != null) {
            d = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Classes can be of any type. (Primitives, Lists or Maps)
I would use `clear()` or `reset()` functions if available.

Is this **really** helpful for GC or should I let Java handle this on it's own?

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: Not really - that's talking about static variables; these are local variables and parameters.

Comment: @Jon - Agreed that they talk about static variables there and local variables here, but the basic premise of assigning the references to `null` is the same and so is the answer to it, which is, no it is not needed and let Java handle it for you.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: The first answer which mentions local variables is way down, with no votes, and the question doesn't talk about local variables at all. I think it's a sufficiently different question to merit staying open.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ Thanks for the link. The accepted answer in slightly contradictory which brings me back to the same point.

Comment: @JonSkeet Also, how would the answer change if we are dealing with Class level variables?

Comment: It would be somewhat less clear-cut - there *can* be situations where it's worth setting fields to null. It's still rare in a good design though.

Answer (score 8):

You should *absolutely* let Java handle this on its own. All you're doing is making your code harder to read and maintain. All the variables you're nulling out are going out of scope at the end of the method anyway - and the GC knows that.

Oh, and in general you shouldn't catch `Exception`... catch *specific* exceptions (if you can actually handle them).

Comment: Assume I am using a Map or another complex type. You are suggesting that I just `clear()` it and let Java handle the rest? Or let Java handle absolutely everything?

Comment: @GauravBhor: No, don't even clear it - let the GC notice that nothing is referring to the entries any more. I can count the number of times I've tried to explicitly "help" the GC on my fingers...

Comment: I think OP is just not aware that he can have `try-finally` without the `catch`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Possibly...

Comment: On top of Jon Skeet's answer, on many occasions, there's no real need for creating new objects for each invocation. You can use caches, fly-weights and various other patterns and mechanisms most of the time. It would be good for you to explore these routes before exploding the VM with instances. Remember that instance creation also takes time.